# python NewRandomAccessFile failed to Create/Open tfhub_module.pb tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using this load model

```
elmo = hub.Module("https://tfhub.dev/google/elmo/2", trainable=True)
```

but it shows

```
NewRandomAccessFile failed to Create/Open: C:\Users\sgarg\AppData\Local\Temp\tfhub_modules\9bb74bc86f9caffc8c47dd7b33ec4bb354d9602d\tfhub_module.pb : The system cannot find the file specified.
; No such file or directory
```

It was working now all of sudden this is showing errors. Now if I check this path

```
C:\Users\sgarg\AppData\Local\Temp\tfhub_modules\9bb74bc86f9caffc8c47dd7b33ec4bb354d9602d
```

there is no  `tfhub_module.pb` but the `saved_model.pb`.

To solve this I have delete `tfhub_modules` folder, then again it will download the model. This has happened many times..

what is the reason for this? Anyway to solve this

Comment: For me even deleting the folder is not helping

Answer (score 0):

Below Link has a fair explanation

https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/tf1_hub_module

It looks like when we use tf2 hub modules `tfhub_modules` is not available. They are only available for tf1

change `elmo = hub.Module("https://tfhub.dev/google/elmo/2", trainable=True)` to `elmo = hub.Module("https://tfhub.dev/google/elmo/1", trainable=True)` then re-try